# Including bibliography in LaTex gives error

Tags: biblatex, kile

I'm writing an IEEE paper and I wanted to use the IEEEtran bibliography style for my research paper. I used the following code to add the bibliography

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\title{Title}
}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{myreferences}
\end{document}
```

When I compile the code using PDFLatex for first time it will not generate any error, infact it generates a new file called myPaper.bbl and when I compile the document for second time I get the following error

```
./myPaper.bbl:3:Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{thebibliography}
```

The contents of `myPaper.bbl` are

```
% Generated by IEEEtran.bst, version: 1.13 (2008/09/30)
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{#1}
\csname url@samestyle\endcsname
\providecommand{\newblock}{\relax}
\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
\providecommand{\BIBentrySTDinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=0pt\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor}{4}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus
\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor\fontdimen3\font minus
  \fontdimen4\font\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBforeignlanguage}[2]{{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\relax
\typeout{** WARNING: IEEEtran.bst: No hyphenation pattern has been}%
\typeout{** loaded for the language `#1'. Using the pattern for}%
\typeout{** the default language instead.}%
\else
\language=\csname l@#1\endcsname
\fi
#2}}
\providecommand{\BIBdecl}{\relax}
\BIBdecl

\end{thebibliography}
```

One more observation I made is, if I change the style of bibliography from IEEEtran to plain, in this case also I notice the same error.

After doing this change what I understood is, the problem is not with the IEEEtran file or plain style file, the only problem is because of the myPaper.bbl file which is being created automatically.

I couldn't understand about the problem more than this as my knowledge in kile documents is limited.

Could someone please help me solve this issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I bet there is an entry in your bib-file responsible (maybe an anescaped `%`). Try to find tis entry using the techniques described in the link above.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE, but the faulty bib part is missing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My current version of `IEEEtran` expects the `biblatex`package. This works with current TeXLive 2014:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IEEEexamples}
\title{Title}

\newcommand\BibTeX{Bib\TeX}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I run `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex -> pdflatex`

[image]